# I make coffee strong enough to enter the Olympics -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

An excerpt from the movie [The Beast from 20,000 Fathoms (1953)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045546/):

> — Five-minute break. It's coffee time.
>   — Good. I need it.
>   — Cream and sugar? Better take both. **I make coffee strong enough to enter the Olympics**.
>   — One or two?
>   — Two, please.

The speaker is speaking figuratively, of course, but what does really she mean she makes coffee strong enough to enter the Olympics?

Comment: What is your understanding of the phrase? What do you think she might mean? You have to indicate a specific issue you have with understanding the usage. You have to tell as what effort **you** made. We are not here to spoon feed you answers.

Comment: Mike is right. the speaker is exaggerating the "strength" of the coffee itself.  Of course the coffee cannot enter the Olympics; this is a joke based on "hyperbole". See definitions 5a and 5b here: http://i.word.com/idictionary/strength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coffee,traditionally, has been known to be a drink that gives energy and keeps you awake and rejuvenated. Going from there, we can safely assume that the character meant that he/she makes coffee so strong that the drinker could finish a cup and be ready to compete in the *Olympics*!.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 4):

He is thinking of an Olympic sport that requires great physical strength, like weightlifting.  In order to enter an Olympic weightlifting competition, an athlete must be much stronger than an average person.  So the speaker is saying that he makes coffee that is much stronger than average coffee.